# SQL - assign column to table variable inside CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, common-table-expression

I need to assign    p3.ID_miasta to @tabela in the following code so that ID_miasta from p3 will be stored in table variable @tabela. It says that syntax is incorrect near '=' when I write @tabela=p3.ID_miasta. Do you know other way that I can do it?

```
create type cat as table
(id int)

declare @tabela cat;

with droga as
(
    select
        @tabela = p3.ID_miasta,
        p2.ID_miasta koniec,
        p1.ID_pociagu ostatni,
        ',' + cast(@poczatek as varchar(max)) + ',' + cast(p2.ID_miasta as varchar(max)) + ',' przesiadki,
        ',' + cast(p1.ID_pociagu as varchar(max)) + ',' pociagi
    from 
        postoje p1 
    inner join 
        postoje p2 on (p1.ID_pociagu = p2.ID_pociagu 
                       and p1.ID_miasta = @poczatek 
                       and p2.ID_miasta <> @poczatek) 
    inner join 
        postoje p3 on (p1.ID_pociagu = p3.ID_pociagu 
                       and (p3.odleglosc between (p1.odleglosc) and (p2.odleglosc)))

    union all

    -- (something not important)
)
```

Comment: Why can't you create the CTE, and then `INSERT INTO @tabela SELECT ID_miasta FROM droga`?

Comment: because I need result of this INSERT INTO @tabela SELECT ID_miasta in this which comes after UNION ALL :)

Comment: Well, you could declare the variable to be the right type.  You can't set a table variable to a scalar value.  Tables *contain* scalar values but are not *equal* to them.

Answer (score 1):

What about two CTEs? Instead of table variable wrap the query in a CTE and use it in the second query.

```
with tabela as
(
    select
        p3.ID_miasta,
        p2.ID_miasta koniec,
        p1.ID_pociagu ostatni,
        ',' + cast(@poczatek as varchar(max)) + ',' + cast(p2.ID_miasta as varchar(max)) + ',' przesiadki,
        ',' + cast(p1.ID_pociagu as varchar(max)) + ',' pociagi
    from 
        postoje p1 
    inner join 
        postoje p2 on (p1.ID_pociagu = p2.ID_pociagu 
                       and p1.ID_miasta = @poczatek 
                       and p2.ID_miasta <> @poczatek) 
    inner join 
        postoje p3 on (p1.ID_pociagu = p3.ID_pociagu 
                       and (p3.odleglosc between (p1.odleglosc) and (p2.odleglosc)))
)
, droga as
(
    select * from tabela

    union all

    -- another select using tabela
)
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer :) unfortunately I am getting error near '=' and it says that variable @tabela is not declared, although I have declared it.

Comment: right, I forgot to remove the table variable, check the updated query